Mutual Authentication via certificate exchange failing in Java: SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
I've built a Java client to a HTTP server protected with mutual authentication. This is not the first time I do this, but this is the first time I had this problem.
The application is a Spring Boot with OpenFeign, but I've reduced this problem to a simple pure Java HttpClient.

Edit:
It appears that the problem is not a mismatch of signature algorithms as stated below. The problem is that the client certificate is not being sent for some unknown reason...
Additionally to the methods described bellow, I also tried to load the certificate and key through their DER files... with the same error...
JDK11 HttpClient mutual tls

It appears that the problem is a mismatch of signature algorithms. Here's a piece of log (-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake):
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|51|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-05-03 14:33:06.372 BRT|CertificateRequest.java:690|Consuming CertificateRequest handshake message (
"CertificateRequest": {
  "certificate types": [rsa_sign, dss_sign, ecdsa_sign]
  "supported signature algorithms": [ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
  "certificate authorities": [...]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|51|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-05-03 14:33:06.376 BRT|X509Authentication.java:221|No X.509 cert selected for [EC, RSA, DSA]
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|51|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-05-03 14:33:06.376 BRT|CertificateRequest.java:781|No available authentication scheme
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|51|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-05-03 14:33:06.377 BRT|ServerHelloDone.java:151|Consuming ServerHelloDone handshake message (
<empty>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|51|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-05-03 14:33:06.377 BRT|CertificateMessage.java:293|No X.509 certificate for client authentication, use empty Certificate message instead
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|51|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-05-03 14:33:06.377 BRT|CertificateMessage.java:324|Produced client Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": <empty list>
)

When verifying the certificate information, the signing algorithm is "SHA256withRSA" which is not present in the list above.
But, (and here comes the odd part) some other tests I do work.

Curl informing the certificate and key works
Insomnia Rest with certificate and key works
Postman with .p12 (PKCS12 / PFX) (the same configured in Java) works

And printing the server's SSL info with OpenSSL, the signature algorithms is different from the list I got with Java.
openssl s_client -connect xxxxx.com:443
...
Acceptable client certificate CA names
...
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, prime256v1, 256 bits
...

Shouldn't these "signature algorithms" be the same? What am I missing here?
I tried to configure my certificate using Java Properties
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "trust.p12");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "PKCS12");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "keys.p12");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");

And programmatically
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("keys.p12"), "password".toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());

        KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        truststore.load(new FileInputStream("trust.p12"), "password".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(truststore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).build();

        String endpoint = "https://xxxxx.com/v1/list";
        String json = "{\"test\": \"test\"}";

        HttpRequest.BodyPublisher requestBody = HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(json, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(endpoint))
                .POST(requestBody)
                .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

Both tries (java 17 and 21) resulted in
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:956)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:133)
    at org.example.SslTest2.main(SslTest2.java:65)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube.checkForHandshake(SSLTube.java:595)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$SSLTubeFlowDelegate.checkForHandshake(SSLTube.java:156)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.errorCommon(SSLFlowDelegate.java:369)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper.onError(SubscriberWrapper.java:412)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadSubscription.signalCompletion(SocketTube.java:645)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.read(SocketTube.java:829)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowTask.run(SocketTube.java:181)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:207)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:280)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:233)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.signalReadable(SocketTube.java:782)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadEvent.signalEvent(SocketTube.java:965)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowEvent.handle(SocketTube.java:253)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.handleEvent(HttpClientImpl.java:1467)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.lambda$run$3(HttpClientImpl.java:1412)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.run(HttpClientImpl.java:1412)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:401)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:434)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube.readAvailable(SocketTube.java:1178)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.read(SocketTube.java:841)
    ... 11 more


"Shouldn't these "signature algorithms" be the same?" - these are the same. Just different string representation. And SHA256withRSA is in there, named RSA+SHA256 or rsa_pkcs1_sha256. So you are probably looking at the wrong place for the explanation of your problem. And the "Remote host terminated the handshake" is likely because your Java client did not send the client certificate. There might be other things which did not match, like the accepted CA.

"certificate authorities": [...] the server sends you a list of CAs it accepts, and your client will examine the list of client certificates whose chain is rooted at one of the CAs. If there are no matches, then ... well, I'm not sure, but you might see the error message you're seeing. Check that you're client certificate chain is rooted by one of those CAs.

@SteffenUllrich, thanks. I wasn't considering "rsa_pkcs1_sha256" the same as "SHA256withRSA" or "RSA+SHA256". But "the TLS 1.2 SignatureAndHashAlgorithm SHA256withRSA has the same id as the TLS 1.3 signature scheme rsa_pkcs1_sha256" (https://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/isasilk/current/iaik/security/ssl/SignatureAlgorithms.html).
I'll try to shift my focus to the "accepted authorities", but I'm pretty sure it's correct.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk The certificate I'm using was directly added to the server's trusted list (not the CA). Since the request is working with other tools, I'll try to focus on what Java is actually sending as a client certificate (if any). Thanks.

If the client can't find a certificate matching the CAs, signature algorithms, etc. sent by the server in the CertificateRequest, it MAY NOT send a certificate, whereupon the server will close the connection if it insists on having a client certificate. So you need to look into what the server sent in CertificateRequest and why your certificate doesn't match it, or else what certificate you did send in the response Certificate message. You can get all this info with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake at the client.

(@President) We already know what Java is sending; your log shows 'Produced client Certificate message / ' (plus it DOESN'T send CertVerify). If the server is set to trust a cert with subject=Alice and issuer=Charlie, it will send 'Alice' as the desired CA, but your cert doesn't have Alice as the CA so it doesn't match and isn't used/sent. If your curl uses OpenSSL -- most but not all do -- that ignores the requested CA(s) and uses the cert regardless so it works even though it's wrong, and I'm pretty sure  Postman does also; I don't know about Insomnia but it certainly could.
